# IIS Giving a 500 Internal Server Error When Serving a PHP file

Tags: php, iis, firephp

I am trying to work on a project locally that uses PHP. I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 with PHP 5.6.2. I was trying to set up FirePHP so I could use that to send out debug messages to the Firebug console.

For the PHP portion, I followed this guide:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Here are some thing I've checked:

- PHP is installed. Checked from cmd.exe with PHP -i.
- FirePHP installed. Console and net tabs enabled. Firefox restarted.
- ASP.NET CGI etc activated
- Double checked the php.ini file as per that guide
- Handler mapping in IIS
- Checked mime type in IIS

Here's the log file from IIS. Nothing is jumping out at me. What did I miss in terms of configuring? (Pastebin with the same text if you find that more convenient: [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/fUSqNHja))

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-11-11 19:12:39
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET / - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 83
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /css/styles.css - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 2
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.min.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery.verticalPlugin.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /pointcloud.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /libs/mjs.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /libs/camera.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /libs/basicCTX.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /grid/grid.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /PCTree/PCTree.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 2
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /markers/markers.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /users/users.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 2
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /pcv.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /map/map.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /axes/axes.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 2
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /interactiveFunctions.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /libs/custom.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 11
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 0
2014-11-11 19:12:39 ::1 GET /jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:12:42 ::1 GET /action.php a=getnode&path=meta&table=kn_leaf_on 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.111+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 2609
2014-11-11 19:14:26 ::1 GET / - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 200 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:14:26 ::1 GET /pointcloud.js - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 304 0 0 1
2014-11-11 19:14:30 ::1 GET /action.php a=getnode&path=meta&table=kn_leaf_on 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 200 0 0 2287
2014-11-11 19:14:30 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 404 0 2 2
2014-11-11 19:14:30 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 404 0 2 0
2014-11-11 19:15:27 ::1 GET /test.php - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 500 0 0 2
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-11-11 19:24:32
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-11-11 19:24:32 ::1 GET /test.php - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+   (Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0+FirePHP/0.7.4 500 0 0 17
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-11-11 19:49:45
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-11-11 19:49:45 ::1 GET /test.php - 8072 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+   (Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0+FirePHP/0.7.4 500 0 0 106
```

Comment: This looks like the access log. There should also be an error log file. That content can help.

Comment: I checked all the logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 (and W3SVC2) and they all look pretty much the same. Is there somewhere else that I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of tinkering, I found someone who wrote a .bat file to do all of the php-iis stuff for you. You already need to have PHP installed. Here is the link, I hope this saves someone else the hours of headache I just went through.

[Rapid PHP Deployment for IIS using a Batch File](http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2014/01/31/rapid-php-deployment-for-iis-using-a-batch-file.aspx)

Just FYI: I still don't know entirely what was wrong with my configuration. But if it works, it works.